# PircBot how to get a hostname

Tags: java, irc

Does anyone know how to use this in PircBots?
http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/index.html
I just need to get a users hostname and ban them. Thanks for reading!

```
                if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("ban")) {
                        if (command[1] != null && command[2] != null) {
                            //Command[1] is the users name.
                            //Command[2] is the reason.
                            //how do i make this ban someone?
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Iv read that, I just don't know how to resolve the host name.
@JimGarrison

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ban with a reason, only kick with a reason. In this case I assume you want to kban, which is kick + ban.

```
            if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("ban")) {
                    if (command[1] != null && command[2] != null) {
                        //Command[1] is the users name.
                        //Command[2] is the reason.
                        //how do i make this ban someone?

                        // ban first 
                        //make sure to input the current channel in "currentChannel"
                        ban(currentChannel, command[1]+"!*@*");

                        // kick with a reason
                        kick(currentChannel, command[1], command[2]);
                    }
                }
```

If your command requires a hostmask, you should let the user specify it - he might want a specific ban, maybe a ban of a whole range etc. Else, generate a poor nickname ban (if the user is offline you could use "whowas" to find out, else you should use "whois". Note that "whowas" may not work.)

From the JavaDoc of PircBot - http://www.jibble.org/javadocs/pircbot/index.html

ban(String channel, String hostmask)
          Bans a user from a channel.

kick(String channel, String nick)
          Kicks a user from a channel.

kick(String channel, String nick, String reason)
          Kicks a user from a channel, giving a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old issue I thought I'd share how I addressed this. I assume you are handling the ban command in the `onMessage` event. In that event youll have to save off the `command[1]` in a Map. Then call

```
sendRawLine("WHO " + command[1]);
```

Override `onServerResponse` and catch code RPL_WHOREPLY, and `split("\\s")` the response. Then you can look up with key in the Map with `splitResult[5]` and the host will be in `splitResult[3]` you can then perform the ban with `String.format("*!*%s", splitResult[3])`